# Is it possible to use late binding on a COM object inside a T4 template?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, t4

My T4 template instantiates an Excel COM object to read some cell values and create C# classes from them. I wrote the Excel reading logics in regular C# first, which works fine. A code snippet that I use in this test is:

```
Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
string cellContents = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Item[1, 1].Value;
```

Transplanting the test code into a T4 template does not work though. The following error is displayed:

> `Error 1: Compiling transformation: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The only way for me to resolve this, is by adding some manual casting:

```
string cellContents = (xlWorkSheet.Cells.Item[1, 1] as Range).Value as string;
```

I was under the impression that T4 uses the "regular" C# compiler and as such, would be able to deal with dynamic binding like regular code can. But apparently, there are differences. In this case, I could resolve my issues because I was able to guess what type to cast to. In general, that is not the case though. Is there a way to make this late binding work in a T4 template?

Comment: what version of t4 are you using?

Comment: Not sure how to check the version of T4, but I am using it inside Visual C# 2010 Express with .NET 4.0

Comment: Regular C# can cope with dynamic binding using the 'dynamic' keyword, as can T4.  Neither can infer it without.  If you define your worksheet as dynamic, then you should be good.

Comment: I do see different results between regular C# and T4 -- no need to define anything as `dynamic` in C#, the line I quoted works fine. I tried changing `xlWorkSheet` to `dynamic` in the T4, but that resulted in an error as well: `Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported` and `Compiling transformation: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?`. I am not missing those references and importing the suggested type did not work either.

Comment: @GarethJ You were right, and I had to add some assembly references as well to make it work (so I *was* missing references to `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.Core`). Thanks!

Comment: @GarethJ Would you mind writing an answer with this resolution, and then also explain why C# works with `xlWorkSheet` defined as `WorkSheet`, but T4 requires `xlWorkSheet` defined as `dynamic` for the same code to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both T4 and C# can cope with dynamic binding using the 'dynamic' keyword.  Neither can infer it without this keyword.

However, in the regular IDE, it's possible to set the flag 'Embed Interop Types" on an assembly reference.  This feature copies the referenced interop types directly into the consuming assembly and also, on the fly, translates 'object' references to 'dynamic'.

Hence the example code in the question compiles in normal C# within the IDE as the 'Item' collection is converted to return a 'dynamic'.

T4 doesn't have an equivalent flag for its 'assembly' directive, so you have to declare your expressions as dynamic manually. For that to work, you have to include the following `assembly` directives to your template as well:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
```

Comment: There is one further workaround, but its pretty ugly.  You can use T4's compilerOptions parameter to send the command line equivalent of the 'Embed Interop Types' flag through to the compiler.  You'd remove the assebmly reference to the interop DLL and instead add the followign parameter to your template directive.  Unfortunately, full paths are needed without env vars.

<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" compilerOptions="/link:\"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll\"" #>